# images disappear after redirecting from FB login/signup in Chrome on Android

Tags: android, html, css, image, google-chrome

I have mobile version of website (React-Redux) and possibility to login/signup with Facebook on it. When I've been redirected from FB after success login/signup then some images have disappeared, but I still can see these elements, their image urls etc.
This problem occurs only in Chrome on Android devices (real and virtual). I was trying to debug this problem via Remote Devices provided by Chrome dev-tools on desktop version of browser but didn't find any explanations of this problem.

For example, this is a button with background image:
HTML:

```
<div class="mobile-col-4">
   <button className="burger-btn" type="button"></button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.burger-btn {
    background: url("/content/img/main_menu.svg") center no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 0;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}
```